# getting value of array/object as string in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am passing my array from node controller to edge template. **edit** *That array is going to convert into long string at view/client side. how would I get that array same as in controller.*

**Template Engine: Edge**

**Server Side: Adonis-JS (Node)**

Controller:

```
//an array of locations
let locations = [
          ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
          ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
          ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
          ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
          ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
        ];

return view.render('dashboard.index', { locations: locations}) //passing to view
```

View:

```
var locations = {{locations}}
//var locations = Object.values({{locations}})

//this how inspect element is allocating values
```

> var locations = Bondi Beach,-33.890542,151.274856,4,Coogee
>   Beach,-33.923036,151.259052,5,Cronulla
>   Beach,-34.028249,151.157507,3,Manly
>   Beach,-33.80010128657071,151.28747820854187,2,Maroubra
>   Beach,-33.950198,151.259302,1

how would I get the values like array to pass in locations var

Comment: I'm confused. What do you want your returned location to look like? Your last yellow block is a giant string, is that what you want?

Comment: no, i actually need the same data in view as in controller, my data turn to long string in view when passing

Comment: you are using node? what templating engine are you using?

Comment: i am using edge template engine with adonis-js as node provider

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

```
//an array of locations
let locations = [
          ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
          ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
          ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
          ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
          ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
        ];

return view.render('dashboard.index', { locations: JSON.stringify(locations)}) //passing to view
```

**View:**

```
var locations = {{{locations}}}
```

> Everything inside `{{ }}` will escape HTML and in order to write raw
>   HTML, you must wrap it inside `{{{ }}}`

https://edge.adonisjs.com/docs/syntax-guide#_interpolation

Comment: this is somehow worked, but `var locations = [[&quot;Bondi Beach&quot;,-33.8....` quotes converted like this, is there a way to skip this conversion

Comment: actullay @ is added when any adonis method or pre-defined variable is called -- didnot work with it

Answer (score 0):

You can nest `forEach` functions to do it:

```js
let locations = [
  ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
  ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
  ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
  ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
  ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
];

var output = [];

locations.forEach(x => x.forEach(y => output.push(y)));

console.log(output);
```

Comment: then pass that `output` to view ?

Comment: @trighati Sure, you can try `return view.render('dashboard.index', { locations: output})`

Comment: still getting the same as always :(

Comment: @trighati Passing a string or an array to view is still getting same result. So the problem can be in another place.

Comment: may be `view.render()` is doing something hidden

Answer (score 0):

**Use `.flat()` :-**

```js
let locations = [
  ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
  ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
  ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
  ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
  ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
];

console.log(locations.flat());
```

Comment: tried adding .flat() on both sides (controller, view) did not work

Answer (score 0):

I know someone recommended a nested forEach, but it's cleaner to use Array.prototype.reduce imo

i.e.

```
const result = locations.reduce((flattened, location) => 
 flattened.concat(...location)
, []);
```